# Why an error probability of 1/3 in BPP?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms

[BPP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity)) is defined as the class of polynomial-time random algorithms which have an error probability of at most 1/3.

But why was 1/3 chosen? If we have an algorithm with some error probability less than 1/2, then we can run it several times, taking the most common result, to obtain an error probability of less than 1/3 while still staying in the same complexity class.

So why isn't BPP instead defined as the algorithms which have an error probability of less than 1/2? Is there something special about 1/3?

Comment: It even says in the article that _In practice, an error probability of ​1⁄3 might not be acceptable, however, the choice of ​1⁄3 in the definition is arbitrary. It can be any constant between 0 and ​1⁄2 (exclusive) and the set BPP will be unchanged._  See also [Prove or refute: BPP(0.90,0.95) = BPP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7820) and [Can BPP be bounded around any constant other than 1/2?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110614/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove or refute: BPP(0.90,0.95) = BPP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/prove-or-refute-bpp0-90-0-95-bpp)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other question. I understand that the classes are equivalent. I am simply trying to understand why the common definition uses 1/3, rather than 1/4, 1/5, or just "some probability less than 1/2". I guess there just isn't a reason and it was the first number the author thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant $1/3$ is completely arbitrary. Let's say that $\mathsf{BPP}_p$ is the class of problems solvable in polytime with error at most $p$. Then $\mathsf{BPP}_p = \mathsf{BPP}_q$ for any $0 < p,q < 1/2$. The simple proof can be found in any decent textbook or lectures notes on complexity theory, and is also a nice exercise. The idea is that you can boost the success probability by running the algorithm several times and take a majority vote (details left to you).

Why do we like $1/3$, then? It's the "simplest" rational number in $(0,1/2)$: for example, it is the rational number in $(0,1/2)$ with the minimal possible denominator, and with the minimal sum of numerator and denominator.